# Gradle version conflict after adding cordova fcm plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

After adding FCM Plugin to project it is not building anymore.

Where cordova is checking GRADLE version? From package.json?
I've tried to change ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION spec on package.json, without success.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
cordova run android
```

```
FCMPlugin: Support for Gradle v4 or lower is deprecated. Please upgrade to a newer version.FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
   > Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'GoogleServicesTask'.
BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I tried to use plugin version 7.0.8 as suggested by Tiago

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.0.8
```

Now I have conflicts with the camera plugin

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\myapp\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:40: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
C:\myapp\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\CordovaUri.java:25: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
C:\myapp\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\FileProvider.java:21: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider {}
                                                            ^
C:\myapp\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:303: error: cannot find symbol
        this.imageUri = new CordovaUri(FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getUriForFile(Activity,String,File)
  location: class FileProvider
C:\myapp\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:801: error: cannot find symbol
                        Uri tmpFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getUriForFile(Activity,String,File)
  location: class FileProvider
5 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Removing fcm plugin camera plugin works again.
Also its weird that even after removing fcm plugin it is still on the project and showing error messages on console

```
FCMPlugin.js:46 FCM: has been created
FCMPlugin.js:41 FCM: Ready error:  Class not found
FCMPlugin.js:43 FCM: Ready!
FCMPlugin.js:23 FCM: Error listening to native events Class not found
```

Comment: Same problem here. I've tried to install a separate and updated gradle, but apparently, it is not using it. And I can't find where I set to use, there is the ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION but I don't think it is that. Tried to update everything, angular, ionic, cordova, android sdk, but did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, we will have to wait for the fcm plugin guys to fix this.
There is this github issue opened a few days ago and it seems that they just have to update the version in the plugin.

A workaround for now is downgrade to a previous version. I used `"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "7.0.8"` and is working.

Github issue: https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/issues/222

Comment: I have found several fcm plugins: cordova-plugin-fcm, cordova-plugin-fcm-ng, cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated, cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated-headup, cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated-apns. 

Why did you choose cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated?

Comment: I used it before and it was the first that worked for me (using ionic 5). Also, at the time it was updated quite frequently while some others not.

Comment: I'm trying to use version 7.0.8, but now its conflicting with the camera plugin
Removing FCM camera plugin works again. I will add error messages on the question
Weird is that even after removing plugin FCMplugin is still on the project reporting error messages on console: FCM: Ready error:  Class not found; FCM: Error listening to native events Class not found

Comment: made downgrade but no I have error
"D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"

Answer (score 0):

If your Cordova project contains plugins/libraries which reference both the Android Support Library and AndroidX, your Android build will fail because the two cannot live side-by-side in an Android build.

This plugin provides a shim to migrate references to the legacy Android Support Library to the new AndroidX mappings in a Cordova Android platform project.

This enables a Cordova project for which AndroidX has been enabled (e.g. using cordova-plugin-androidx) to successfully build even if it contains plugins which reference the legacy Support Library.

The plugin uses a hook script to replace any legacy Support Library references:

Gradle artifacts in app/build.gradle and project.properties with new artifact mappings
Class/package names in AndroidManifest.xml or the Java source code (of Cordova plugins) with new class mappings.

Comment: npm i cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter